# VLC: cannot open ALSA device "default": Connection refused

Tags: alsa, vlc

When starting VLC I get:

```
[000055d167ad3e80] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": Connection refused
[000055d167ad3e80] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59ce548870] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated
```

and VLC complains about audio not working.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alsa limits the number of clients (not sure where the limit is or why there is a limit. Post a comment if you know).

Killing one of the other clients (in my case another (paused) VLC) made it work.